# Sum Sales quantity up to a specific date - T SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I m trying to get the sum of `Sales QTY` per `Item Code` and per `Date` but i can not think an possible solution. One of my thoughts is to use `RANK()` function.

**Table**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: @JNevill i have change the structure of my output. could you please check it again?

Answer (score 1):

Using [OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) we can get a running total. [Bert Wagner](https://bertwagner.com/2017/07/18/heres-a-quick-way-to-generate-a-running-total-in-sql-server/) has a good blog post that goes into more detail on this topic.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable
(
    ItemCode VARCHAR(10)
    , Date DATE
    , SalesQTY INT
)

INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES
('Item A', '01/01/2020', 1)
, ('Item A', '02/01/2020', 2)
, ('Item A', '03/01/2020', 3)
, ('Item B', '01/01/2020', 4)
, ('Item A', '04/01/2020', 5)
, ('Item B', '02/01/2020', 6);

SELECT 
    Date
    , ItemCode
    , SUM(SalesQTY) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemCode ORDER BY Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS SalesQTY
FROM 
    #MyTable
```

Comment: This gives me an error, the same error as the comment in the Bert blog post

Comment: @Error1004 I have tested this code and it works fine. However, it will only work on SQL Server 2012 or newer. Which version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: SQL Sever 2008. i Found a work around! Thanks for your time

Comment: I tagged your question with 2008. In the future try to tag or mention which version you are on so answers can be tailored for your use case.